# concurrent update on different documents in same collection with index

Tags: arangodb, rocksdb

In the documentation [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/transactions-locking-and-isolation.html), under locks section, I see "However, if two concurrent transactions attempt to modify the same document or index entry, there will be a write-write conflict"

Consider, I have a collection named food with below two documents and an index on the fields "category, color".

*food*:

```
  {
       name: apple,
       category:  fruit
       color: red  
  },
  {
       name: raspberry,
       category: fruit
       color: red
  }
```

if I have a transaction T1 modifying the first document(apple) and another transaction T2 modifying the second document(raspberry) concurrently. Though they are different documents, can i get write-write conflict because they have same value of for category and color on which the index is built?